# How to create a simple class Queue in python 3.6?

Tags: python, queue, python-3.6

I'm beginner. Here is my code:

```
class Queue: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
    def dequeue(self):
        self.queue.pop(O) 
    def enqueue(self,element):
        self.queue.append(element)
q=Queue()
q.enqueue('dog')
print(q)
```

But! I see this:

```
<__main__.Queue object at 0x00A3FC10>
```

What is it? How to create this class than?

Comment: Everything is fine. This is normal. I don't know why you expected anything else.

Comment: Oh, yes ?
Can I ask you, please, why? I'm really frustrated now. Can I change it?

Comment: Do you want to print the items stored in the Queue ?

Comment: Please put your code as text into your question. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: "`<__main__.Queue object at 0x00A3FC10>` What is it?" It's the default representation of your `Queue` instance. If you don't know what that means please read about `repr` in the docs. BTW, that `Queue` isn't very efficient. Real code should use `collections.deque`, but I guess this is homework code.

Answer (score 2):

That is the default display representation of an instance of your class.  The default is to display the class name and the address of its instance in memory.  You can override `__repr__` and `__str__` to customize the representation:

```
class Queue: 

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.queue.pop(0) # probably want to return what you dequeue.

    def enqueue(self,element):
        self.queue.append(element)

    # Customize debug representation...you want to know it is a Queue and what is in it.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Queue({self.queue})'

    # Customize print representation...may just want to see the list.
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.queue}'

q=Queue()
q.enqueue('dog')
q.enqueue('cat')
print(repr(q))
print(q)
print(f'popped {q.dequeue()}')
print(q)
```

Output:

```
Queue(['dog', 'cat'])
['dog', 'cat']
popped dog
['cat']
```